# How to make propper language switch?

Tags: shortcut-keys, language-support

Currently I am switching languages with

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current n
```

with shorcut "Super +n" where n can be 0,1,2.
However its works pretty laggy:

- If i use shortcut, and continue to type, words will be pringted with
  previous language for several seconds
- If i delete text and then    switch language, than deleted words will
  be pasted on position of    cursor

Comment: Super+n is already used for window switching. I'd recommend you change your custom keyboard shortcut to Super+Ctrl+n. You could also disable the system shortcut if you like.

Comment: i disabled system shortcut prior making my own, as it was not usefull for me